# How is numpy.einsum implemented?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I want to understand how is einsum function in python implemented. I found the source code in `numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src` file but couldn't completely understand it. In particular I want to understand how does it creates the required loops automatically?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(2,3,4,5)
b = np.random.rand(5,3,2,4)

ll = np.einsum('ijkl, ljik ->', a,b) # This should loop over all the 
# four indicies i,j,k,l. How does it create loops for these indices automatically ?

# The assume that under the hood it does the following 
sum1 = 0
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(4):
            for l in range(5):
                sum1 = sum1 + a[i,j,k,l]*b[l,j,i,k]
```

Thank you in advance

ps: This question is not about how to use numpy.einsum

Comment: For a starting point, look at line [1093](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L1093); which then leads to the do loop at lines [1118-1120](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L1118), with `sop` being a function to calculate the "sum of products".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to understand how does it creates the required loops automatically?

Well, it does not create the loops the way you think it does. In this case, it creates an iterator operating over multiple arrays and then use it in a generic main loop. In the more general case, there are two main loops: one to iterate over the output array items and one to perform a reduction.

The main function is [`PyArray_EinsteinSum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/cb28cd17d01a6a867517a3b8b3ea4fbb0370be10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L770). In your case, it takes an unoptimized path and end up [creating a basic iteration function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/cb28cd17d01a6a867517a3b8b3ea4fbb0370be10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L1084) based on the iterator created previously (ie. `iter`). This function is [`get_sum_of_products_function`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e6d5529dccfec7d1a66929f67f6b04b6ec12f790/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum_sumprod.c.src#L1208). It basically analyze the einsum operation so to find the best (sum of product) function to call based on a lookup table (like [`_outstride0_specialized_table`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e6d5529dccfec7d1a66929f67f6b04b6ec12f790/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum_sumprod.c.src#L1099)). In your specific case, `double_sum_of_products_outstride0_two` is called. Numpy use a template system so to generate this function automatically at build time (*.c.src files are template files converted to *.c files based on predefined basic comments). In this case, the function is generated from [`@name@_sum_of_products_outstride0_@noplabel@`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e6d5529dccfec7d1a66929f67f6b04b6ec12f790/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum_sumprod.c.src#L691) and once computed by the C preprocessor it gives something like the following function:

```c
static void double_sum_of_products_outstride0_two(int nop, 
                                                    char **dataptr,
                                                    npy_intp const *strides, 
                                                    npy_intp count)
{
    npy_double accum = 0;
    char *data0 = dataptr[0];
    npy_intp stride0 = strides[0];
    char *data1 = dataptr[1];
    npy_intp stride1 = strides[1];

    while (count--)
    {
        accum += (*(npy_double *)data0) * (*(npy_double *)data1);
        data0 += stride0;
        data1 += stride1;
    }

    *((npy_double *)dataptr[2]) = (accum + (*((npy_double *)dataptr[2])));
}
```

As you can see, there is only one main loop iterating over the previously generated iterator. In your case, `stride0` and `stride1` are both equal to 8, `data0` and `data1` are the raw input arrays, `dataptr` is the raw output array and `count` is set to 120 initially. Note that the fact both strides are equal to 8 is surprising at first glance since the einsum does not iterate on the two array contiguously. This is because the second array is copied and reorder because Numpy cannot create a uniform view based on the einsum parameters.

Note that the fallback case use for the example code is not particularly optimized and it only produce one value. For example, the much more optimized [`double_sum_of_products_contig_contig_outstride0_two`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e6d5529dccfec7d1a66929f67f6b04b6ec12f790/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum_sumprod.c.src#L475) function can be called from [`unbuffered_loop_nop2_ndim2`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/cb28cd17d01a6a867517a3b8b3ea4fbb0370be10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L610) for the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3, 10)
b = np.random.rand(3, 10)

for i in range(1):
    ll = np.einsum('ij, ij -> i', a, b)
```

In this case, the `double_sum_of_products_contig_contig_outstride0_two` performs the reductions for a given output item and `unbuffered_loop_nop2_ndim2` iterate over the output array.

If the expression `ij, ij -> j` is instead used in the above code, then the function `double_sum_of_products_contig_two` is called which operates the same way than `double_sum_of_products_contig_contig_outstride0_two` except it reads/writes on the whole output line during the reduction.