# Comparison of Looping and Einsum Operations on a List of Arrays for Speed Optimization

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I want to make use of the einsum to speed up a code as following:

As simple example using a list of 2 (3,3) arrays called dcx:

That i created:

```
In [113]: dcx = [np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), np.arange(10,19).reshape(3,3)]; dcx
Out[113]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]),
 array([[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]])]
```

I wanted to perform the following operation:

```
In [114]: Ax = np.zeros((2,2))
     ...: for i in range(2):
     ...:         for j in range(2):
     ...:             Ax[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dcx[i], dcx[j].T))

In [115]: Ax
Out[115]: 
array([[ 450., 1530.],
       [1530., 5310.]])

The time taken ~ 0.001009225845336914 sec
```

Then i tried using einsum as folowing:

```
x =np.array(dcx)
In [117]: np.einsum('ikl,jml->ij', x,x)
Out[117]: 
array([[ 450, 1530],
       [1530, 5310]])
```

And the time taken in second in almost zero,

So i thought that einsum should be faster, i extended my example to more complex case as following:

dCx is now a list of 40 (40,40) arrays.

I noticed that the time take by:

```
In [114]: Ax = np.zeros((40,40))
     ...: for i in range(40):
     ...:         for j in range(40):
     ...:             Ax[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dcx[i], dcx[j].T))

Is 0.02168726921081543 sec
```

while the time taken by the einsum:

```
array_list = []
for _ in range(40):
    array = np.random.rand(40, 40)
    array_list.append(array)
t0 = time.time()
x =np.array(array_list)
np.einsum('ikl,jml->ij', x,x)
t1 = time.time()
print(f"Execution time : {t1-t0} sec")

0.15755462646484375 sec
```

I am confused why einsum now takes longer time? i wanted to make use of ituse it to speed up more complex code with dCx of dimensions (3000,3000,3000) where my loops takes very long time.

Comment: You compare codes apparently not working on the same arrays. The first code uses `dcx` while the second uses `array_list`. What is supposed to be `array_list` in the second code? Can you provide a fully reproducible code ? (eg. something we can copy past without missing variables)

Comment: With a (40,40,40) array, `timeit` gives me `148ms` for the iterative, and `260ms` for the `einsum`.  That's consistent with my experience, that often a modest number of iterations on a complex task is faster than the equivalent whole-array operation.  'memory mangement' (paging, caching etc) complicates the running of very large array operations.

Comment: @hpaulj I see, do you suggest any alternative methods to speed up the loop code for huge matrices ? 

 [114]: Ax = np.zeros((3000,3000))
     ...: for i in range(3000):
     ...:         for j in range(3000):
     ...:             Ax[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dcx[i], dcx[j].T))

Comment: @JérômeRichard array_list is the dCx with dimensions (40,40,40) i edited the post now to include the array_list  generations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both of the methods are inefficient**. Einsum surprizingly fail to find the optimal einsum path in this case (even with the optional `optimal` parameter set). The `dot` approach is faster here (possibly because it explicitly benefit from the highly-optimized BLAS matrix multiplication implementation), but it is still clearly inefficient algorithmically since many operations are not actually needed.

One can drastically reduce the number of operation by **factorizing the operations**. This kind of optimisation requires you to do a bit of **maths**. Let us describe mathematically what `np.sum(np.dot(x, y))` (with `x = dcx[i]` and `y = dcx[j]`) does and factorize the resulting expression:

[image]

For each `(i,j)`, we can pre-compute the inner terms of the expression and reuse them:

```py
tmp1 = np.sum(dcx[i], axis=0)      # Sum over i
tmp2 = np.sum(dcx[j], axis=0)      # Sum over j
Ax[i, j] = np.dot(tmp1, tmp2)      # Final sum over k
```

This is a huge improvement over the initial code since this approach runs in `O(n**4)` while the initial one runs in `O(n**5)` (due to the expensive matrix multiplication), where `n` is the side of the `dcx` matrix (40 in your example).

We can do better: we can pre-compute the sum of all `dcx` slice in a row so not to recompute them. Here is the final code:

```py
tmp = np.sum(dcx, axis=1)          # Sum over i and j for all planes
Ax = tmp @ tmp.T                   # Final sum over k for all planes
```

This approach runs in `O(n**3)`. It is **optimal** because the size of the input is `O(n**3)` too. It should be **>1_000_000 times faster** than the initial approach for n=3000, not to mention the code is also shorter!

Here is performance results for n=40:

```
einsum:     131_885 µs
loop:        17_142 µs
proposed:        47 µs   <----
```

---

Related post: [How is numpy.einsum implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952005/how-is-numpy-einsum-implemented/72986292#72986292)